# How to catch Run Time in Java?

Tags: cpu, java, intellij-idea

I am catching CPU time of my java program.I am using intellij and which option is best to catch exact CPU time.

```
(1)javavisualvm
(2)from intellij console
(3)from java terminal
```

Comment: Are you wanting to access that time within Java or just see how long your program takes to run?

Comment: I want to see how long my program takes to run.

Comment: On Linux and Unix systems you can use `/usr/bin/time -v java /path/to/class` - will show all sorts of cool output including user time (real time), cpu time, times memory cache was hit, times swapping had to occur, etc.